# Delete files from the absolute paths

Tags: batch-file, cmd, delete-file

I must gather information about the two directories(dir). The first directory contains files with names 1.txt, 3 txt, 5.txt, second directory, respectively, 2.txt, 4.txt, 6.txt. and redirect the output to another file. Contents of files doesn't matter.
After that, I have to sort the files in alphabetical order.

Next, I'd  take the first three files and delete them by absolute path, it means, that from the first directory I'd remove the files named 1.txt 3.txt and from the second directory I'd remove the file 2. txt.

We don't know filenames, that are in directories.

Who can help me?

```
@echo off
cd MainDirectory
dir /d folder1 folder2  > paths.txt
findstr /l "Diskname:" paths.txt > sorted.txt
del paths.txt
dir /b folder1 folder2 > paths.txt
findstr /l ".txt" paths.txt > minifiles.txt
del paths.txt

sort /+1 minifiles.txt > pathfiles.txt
del minifiles.txt

::next string give me just one absolute path. Last path. Path to the folder2
for /F "tokens=3 delims= " %%i in (sorted.txt) do @echo %%i > sortedFINAL.txt

::next string assigns the tmp a value : absolute path Diskname:\....\\...\folder2
For /F "Delims=" %%I In (sortedFINAL.txt) Do Set tmp=%%~I

echo %tmp%
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dir folder1 /b >>files.txt
dir folder2 /b >>files.txt
del folder1\1.txt /f /q
del folder1\3.txt /f /q
del folder2\2.txt /f /q
```

You can remove the `/b` switch from `dir` if you want more details on the directory.